# how to parse xml without dtd validation and using lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I've tried using the following code which has **invalid** dtd/xml

```
<city>
<address>
      <zipcode>4455</zipcode>
</address>
```

I'm trying to parse with with lxml

like this,

```
from lxml import etree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser(dtd_validation=False)
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_data,parser)
print(tree.xpath('//zipcode'))
```

Unfortunately, This code still gives xml errors,

Any idea how i can get a **non-validating** parse of the above xml?

Comment: what do you mean by **invalid dtd** in that sample XML? Is it that the `<city>` tag is not closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by '*invalid dtd*' you meant that the `<city>` tag is not closed in above XML sample, then your document is actually *invalid XML* or frankly it isn't XML at all because it doesn't follow XML rules.

You need to fix the document somehow to be able to treat it as an XML document. For this simple unclosed tag case, setting `recover=True` will do the job :

```
from lxml import etree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_data,parser)
print(tree.xpath('//zipcode'))
```

Comment: yes this works!, additionally using recover=True does'nt validate when the xml string starts from `junkvalue <city></city>`  do you have a suggestion to "recover" from this?

Comment: where `junkvalue` has no open and close angular `<` `>` chars and placed  before the main xml string

Comment: Hmm... for now, I don't have anything on top of my head to "auto-fix" beyond what `recover=True` can do